# google maps: dynamic canvas drawing in mapview

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-canvas

i'm currently having trouble to add dynamicly a marquer on my mapview, certainly due to my lack in java knowledge :(

which parameter should i give to my canvas  to make this work?
when i fee the coordinates, the map goes where i want but i have no maker

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.goMap)).setOnClickListener(
                      new OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View v) {



                            mapView.invalidate();
                        // On récupère notre EditText
                         EditText UserName = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.getLon));
                         EditText Password = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.getLat));

                         // On garde la chaîne de caractères
                          _lat = UserName.getText().toString();
                          _long = Password.getText().toString();

                         latTest =  Double.parseDouble(_lat)* 1E6;
                         longTest =  Double.parseDouble(_long)* 1E6;

                         p3 = new GeoPoint(
                                    (int) (latTest ), 
                                  (int) (longTest ));

                          //---add the marker---
                          Bitmap bmp3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                               getResources(), R.drawable.maps_position_marker); 
                          Canvas canvas= new Canvas();
                           canvas.drawBitmap(bmp3, screenP3ts.x-15, screenP3ts.y-30, null);


                         mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p3, screenP3ts);
                            mapController.animateTo(p3);
                            mapController.setCenter(p3);

                         Toast.makeText(TheMap.this, "lat=" + latTest + " et " + "long= " + longTest, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                         }
                         });
```

in my intial code, the overlay which has all good parametres it needs, is loaded in the `onCreate ()` methode and it works fine but as i mentioned i can't figure out how to add the marker in the `onclick ()` methode. I know what i did is wrong but i don't know how to do :(

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing to the canvas using `screenP3ts` before you actually transform the lat / lon into screen coordinates.  You need this:

```
Bitmap bmp3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
        getResources(), R.drawable.maps_position_marker); 
Canvas canvas= new Canvas();

mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p3, screenP3ts);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp3, screenP3ts.x-15, screenP3ts.y-30, null);
```

Comment: do you know how to fix the picture on that particular point?
because when i move the map, the ressource doesn't stay fixed to the feeded coordinates

Comment: You need to get updated screen coordinates each time the map moves.  The best way to do this is actually to override the `onDraw()` method.

Comment: can you give me an example how to dit with that specifi class.. i looked for a way and tried since but got errors in my code

Comment: You need to implement your own MapView class and then you can add any overlays you want.

Comment: Actually that is what i did.. it works with all markers (points) loaded with the onCreate () methode but for the onclick() one, the marker is not fixed with point when the map is moved

Comment: Are you storing the lat / long of the click and updating the screen coords as the map moves?

Comment: i managed to do it finally. I did what u told me but i needed to create a separate overlay class which will be called after the onclick (). Actually what i was doing is that a person  feeds corrdinates and the map shows the place choosen, thx once again